# RTRIM working with SELECT but not with UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've moved a database from DB2 to SQL Server 2016 using Microsoft's Migration tool. Many of my source tables in DB2 are the CHARACTER data type and it maps to a CHAR in SQL Server. Once the tables are moved over I'm getting trailing spaces in my SQL Server tables. Using a SELECT I can remove them in query results using LTRIM(RTRIM(column)), but if I use

```
 UPDATE table SET column = LTRIM(RTRIM(column))
```

the trailing spaces remain.

Comment: You're using a `char`... That's a fixed width column. For example a `char(100)` will *always* be 100 characters long, and will be padded with trailing spaces to do so. [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `CHAR` is fixed-length in DB2 as well. Are you sure the whitespace wasn't there to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to map to a `VARCHAR()` in SQL Server.

The `CHAR()` data type is fixed length with trailing spaces for shorter strings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is part of the standard, not just SQL Server. DB2's CHAR is fixed-length as well. All databases have quirks though and DB2 has a few left over from the mainframe era

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . I'm not sure if all databases actually *store* the spaces.  But `char` versus `varying char` is part of the standard.